# How to keep house 40º cooler than outside?

Tags: air-conditioning

I live in a desert environment where many summer days are over 120ºF.  I would like to keep the inside below 80.  My current AC cannot achieve this even if it runs all day long.  I've read from several sources that a typical AC is designed to lower the temperature about 20º.  What can be done in this situation?  Are there specialty units that can lower the temperature more than this?

Before anyone mentions a swamp cooler, I've already looked up those charts, and it seems like with typical humidity of 5% that will not be able to cool the house below 80 either.

Comment: Desert=sun.  First you find a way to keep the sun from hitting the house, awnings over the windows, white roofs/walls.  Extra insulation in the roof/attic and walls will not hurt either.  The best is probably an underground house, but probably not something you can do now.

Comment: Just FYI, a full, properly sized HVAC system should be able to cool more than 20 degrees F. My house in California can hold an inside temperature of 75 or less with an outside temperature of 100+.

Comment: give us some meat on the bone, house size, AC size, windows, budget, DYI skills ...

Comment: The 20 degree statistic is an irrelevant technicality of how the AC works.  There are freezers in your locality right?   If you can *keep* the cool in, you can keep cooling it more.

Comment: Did it ever work? If it never worked, that's one thing. If it used to work, it might well be broken.

Comment: How well sealed is your house?

Answer (score 1):

More insulation, which your house almost certainly is woefully lacking.

If your unit can't move more heat, you can get cooler by giving it less heat to move. It's simple math. While my cooling needs are limited, I use the exact same technology operating as a heat pump to achieve differentials of as much as 83 °F for roughly 2000 square feet with 27KBTUs/hr - because my building is well-insulated.

Or you can throw a larger unit at it, with the attendant larger operating costs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your home was properly build with ducting size corespoding to the AC size and the Heat Exhanger capacity.

So there is nothing much you can do here to improve.

Wall and Roof

Let's assume your Wall and Roof insulation was properly done so there is not much you can do here without major remodeling. You can verify that by using infrared thermometer and measure outside vs inside wall temperature on multiple spots.

Now you will have few numbers to guide you.

The outside air temperature..

The inside air temp (the AC)

The inside wall temp in AC room, should be same as Air temp set..

Wall temp outside in full sun. Wall temp inside on the opposite side of full sun wall is 105F --> this will give you the insulation quality.

From here there are two options:

1- Insulate the exterior walls with rigid foam (from outside.) Since you do not need that in winter, go to option 2.

2- Install motorized vertical shades (a DIY job) that you can lower when needed. Hang them from soffit and supply 24 volt. That alone will give you about 20-30F temperature reduction on the walls from direct sun exposure.

Some numbers from my place today:

Exterior air 110 F

Exterior wall in full sun 155F.

Exterior wall in shade 110F

Interior wall in shade = AC setting 80F

Interior wall on opposite side of full sun but no AC in the room 105F.

My insulation provide >20F temp reduction

Web search therm: ***motorized outdoor patio shades***